# Passing information to another Activity using intent on click of Context Menu

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to send extra information using put extra, to another activity when the user clicks a context menu. The context menu loads the activity but the information does not appear on the other activity. The code below shows what I have tried.

```
    public void in(int position) {
        // gets the position of the item in my array list
        Cars c = cars.get(position);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);

        i.putExtra("TITLE", c.getCarsTitle());
        startActivity(i);
    }

    // create context menu
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.cars_menu_layout, menu);

    }

    // runs on long click
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.register:

            // runs the method that starts the intent
            in(0);

            return true;
        case R.id.view:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

Comment: please post your complete code along with both the activities.
It will be helpful if you can order the code too

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
i.putExtra("TITLE", c.getCarsTitle().toString);
```